# Response variables JMETER

Tags: regex, performance, testing, jmeter

I'm trying to get only the first 4 values ​​from the result of a resquisition and that return is in json.
How can I do this?
I looked in the apache manual and what is presented there I can not do

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use Regular Expression like `{"d":"(\d{4})`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex 4 Digits]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I can capture the value of the response by putting the value in the "regular expression extractor" = [1-9] {1,4}